# Ruby on Rails Gem or Plugin Rails Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heliconzoo

I am working on a rails 2.3.4 application that I am trying to port over to run with IIS and Helicon Zoo.  The problem I am encountering is an exception in:

```
c:\Zoo\Workers\ruby\lib\app.rb
```

where the following exception is getting raised on line ~32:

```
 STDERR
[tid-21079944] Only Rails 2.3.x and Rails 3.x are currently supported. (RuntimeError)    
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:33:in `build_app' 
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:16:in `initialize' 
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in `new' 
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in `initialize' 
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30:in `new' 
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30
```

This is puzzling for me since the version of rails this application was running on previously was 2.3.4. The working hypothesis I am going on is that rails somehow can run plugins in a legacy mode? Does this make sense? I am thinking that Helicon Zoo does not support rolling back in this legacy mode prior to 2.3.4.

I hacked up the app.rb file a bit to get at the rails version.

Invoking: Rails.version.to_s
I am getting: 2.2.2

Searching the code base for '2.2.2' I see that this project depends on an actionpack lib version 2.2.2.

Further, do rails plugin versions typically follow the 'rails' version they depend on?
Is it possible to run plugins that depend on an older 'rails' version than what they run with?

Comment: The problem may be that it expects 2.3 and not 2.2
This limitation might be backed up by some issues occurring on the earlier versions.

Comment: @TonyCool I am definitely running with rails 2.3.4. From the Helcion Zoo Web Console invoking "rails -v" yields "Rails 2.3.4".

Comment: Could it be that the plugin checks the Rails version incorrectly? If you are using Zoo there must be a Ruby installation in your system, like in C:\Ruby19 Try to navigate there with system console and check if rails is installed in this global installation. Try to remove Rails from this global installation, if it is there.
Since "rails -v" command from web console yields correct version your environment seems to be configured right. But the plug-in may ignore GEM_HOME and other environment settings and check Rails version by hardcoded Ruby installation path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I had installed rails 2.3.4 with gem but had copied a 2.2.2 version of rails with the project to the Helicon Zoo web root directory. The actionpack lib is part of rails. I was thinking it was a separate library.